# Auto renewal of SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I have created a report which represents daily sales. It has a Date parameter. Users of this report want it to renew, for instance, each hour, without clicking anywhere, and show results on the screen. They don't want to receive it by mail, they want to see it renewed version each hour on browser.

If it didn't have any parameter, I heard that it is possible to arrange schedule in browser itself, but it has a parameter (Date).

Is there a way to do this? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You have to be careful here because to do this you will have to open the session length for any one report being viewed to a large window of time. This will leave open pipelines to your DB. Probably not the smartest thing to do. I would assume tho that if you have user interaction with a date parameter that you are going to be out of luck as   I don't believe reporting services has this ability. You would be able to convert the report to an aspx page and control its functionality that way, but that would be a major overhaul.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with SFrejofsky to be careful about DB security. When I've needed to do this in the past though, there is a report auto refresh property that you can set that worked well.
Click anywhere outside of the report. Then in the report properties pane (if not already displaying... with report selected, press F4, or go to View-->Properties Window) set the auto refresh property (in number of seconds) to how often it should refresh (in your case... 1 hour... set to 3600), then with the report rendered, any new data since report first rendered or last refresh, should display upon the refresh.
I've done this when users run a report that they leave open for a bit and new data is being sent to the DB every couple minutes or less and they want it refreshed like every 30 seconds. I'd be curious though about the need to keep the report open for so long and a required auto-refresh of an hour.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Curiosity getting to me here how would the auto refresh work with a user supplied parameter. Does it retain the current parameter selections and in essence just reinvoke the view report call?

Comment: I'm also curious about that. User will run report once with one parameter, say, March 2, and it won't change during whole day.

Answer (score 0):

I have to post a comment to your comment as an answer because I don't have enough reputation yet to add a commemt.
I went back to reports that I did as I described above. I see that the reason it worked in my cases is because there is a date range for the reports (from datetime and to datetime) which are defaulted to today at 12am to today at 11:59pm. So the reason this worked in my case is because when the business users are looking at this during the day, the new records will display, as they will still fall within that datetime range. All parameters for the report have default values. I tried changing one of the datetime values and running the report. It ran with the new datetime value, but each time it refreshes (every 30 seconds), the datetime doesn't get reevaluated. This is due to a long standing issue(?) ...opened in April 2011... with SSRS and not reevaluating default parameters that are changed by the user, that many people out there have mentioned they would like, and have the need, to have control over, and Microsoft just always responding with... it is not a bug, this is working as designed, as there isn't a way, currently, of knowing if the parameter was changed by the user.
So in my case, this was suffice, but I can see that based on the report requirements, it may not be a viable solution in every case.